# Android directory/folder picker with Select button

Tags: android, android-intent, storage-access-framework

I am new to android programming and trying to launch file explorer using SAF to select a folder/directory. Below code works fine when selecting a file, however, I want user to select a folder (and/or create a new folder).

1. onActivityResult() doesn't get invoked on selecting a folder. Is it possible to trigger this event?
2. How to get "select" and "new folder" buttons in the file explorer as shown in the attached image?

   `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.setType("*/*");
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"), PICK_REQUEST_CODE);`

[File explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08DFc.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am new to android programming and trying to launch file explorer using SAF to select a folder/directory.

Your code is not using the Storage Access Framework.

> however, I want user to select a folder (and/or create a new folder).

You cannot use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for that. You would need to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, and that requires Android 5.0.

Comment: That's awesome. Sorry, I meant "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT". Both seem to produce similar results however. +1

Comment: @adit305: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` are both "pick a piece of content" actions. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` is "pick a folder/directory/container/tree of content".

Comment: can we set a specific folder and do not allow to select others? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267192/saf-with-initial-path-prevent-changing-initial-path-in-manager