# SAF with initial path - prevent changing initial path in manager

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, android-storage

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
    putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true)
    putExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true)
    putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true)
}

...

intent.putExtra(
    DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,
    uri // for example for /emulated/0/Audiobooks
)
```

But a user can select a different path in the file manager. How can I block it to one specific path?

I just need to get permission for the specific and the exact folder, a user should have a choice to select others...

[image]

So basically he can select other path instead of Audiobooks and press "**Use this folder**" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I block it to one specific path?

That is not possible, sorry. It is the user's device, and the user's content. The user gets to decide what tree to share with your app (if any).

Comment: so what is the point to set initial uri?

Comment: as developers we set initial uri and pray that a user won't select a different path :) yes we can then check the picked uri and show some error that is the wrong one but this is boilerplate code and UI, for most apps it should set a specific path, it can not be random, Google didn't make it very good, it's not about what content user has on his device and what he allows, it's about that apps are not supposed to work with random content a user picks and allows

Comment: @user924: "so what is the point to set initial uri?" -- if you have a `Uri` from a previous SAF request, you can request that the SAF UI start there. That is a request (not necessarily honored) and it does not lock the user into only that location. "or most apps it should set a specific path, it can not be random" -- computer programmers have been handling "random" selection of files and directories from platform-supplied UI literally for decades. See, for example, the file-open dialogs available on every desktop OS.

Comment: everything is usually more simple for smartphones, but ok, I guess there is no other choice as to tell a user that the selected path is wrong one please try again